# front end registration form with select dropdown option

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, request, selectlist

I'm using on my wordpress website a custom front end registration form including input fields and a select list.

eveything works fine, but I have an issue with a select dropdown list, I can't get the value selected, nothing is stored.

here is how i try to get the value from the select list.

('acf[field_5d3f09ea80429]' is the name of my select tag.)

```
$fonction = $_POST['acf[field_5d3f09ea80429]'];
```

here is my full select tag :

```
<select id="acf-field_5d3f09ea80429" class="" name="acf[field_5d3f09ea80429]" data-ui="0" data-ajax="0" data-multiple="0" data-placeholder="Choisir" data-allow_null="0"><option value="collectivites">Collectivités</option><option value="acteur_publique">Acteur publique</option><option value="chercheur">Chercheur</option><option value="citoyen">Citoyen</option><option value="travailleur_social">Travailleur social</option><option value="entreprise">Entreprise</option><option value="autre">Autre</option></select>
```

I think this is what's wrong in my code, I'm using this code to get the values from my input fields, and it works fine :

```
$nom = esc_sql($_REQUEST['nom']);
```

and the input field :

```
<input type="text" name="nom" required placeholder="Nom" value="<?php if( ! empty($nom) ) echo $nom; ?>" />
```

I think this part is missing from my select tag, but I'm not sure :

```
value="<?php if( ! empty($nom) ) echo $nom; ?>"
```

and here is my Full Code with the form, can anybody help me solving this issue ?

```
<?php

if ( $_POST ) {

    $error = 0;

    /* NOM --------------------*/

    $nom = esc_sql($_REQUEST['nom']); 

    /* PRENOM --------------------*/

    $prenom = esc_sql($_REQUEST['prenom']); 

    /* FONCTION --------------------*/

    $fonction = $_POST['acf[field_5d3f09ea80429]'];

    /* USERNAME --------------------*/

    $username = esc_sql($_REQUEST['username']); 

    if ( strlen($username) < 6 ) {

        echo "<div class='alert_form'>Pas assez de caractère</div>"; 

        $error = 1;

    }

    if ( preg_match('/\s/',$username) ) {

        echo "<div class='alert_form'>pas d'espace</div>"; 

        $error = 1;

    }

    /* EMAIL --------------------*/

    $email = esc_sql($_REQUEST['email']);

    if ( !preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email) ) { 

        echo "<div class='alert_form'>Please enter a valid email</div>"; 
        $error = 1;

    }

    /* MOT DE PASSE --------------------*/

    $password = esc_sql($_REQUEST['password']); 

    /* VALIDATION --------------------*/

    if ( $error == 0 ) {

        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email ); 

    }

}

if ( $error != 2 ) { ?> 

<?php if(get_option('users_can_register')) { ?>

<form id="register_form" action="" method="post"> 

    <div class="form_row"> 

        <input type="text" name="nom" required placeholder="Nom" value="<?php if( ! empty($nom) ) echo $nom; ?>" /> 

    </div>

    <div class="form_row"> 

        <input type="text" name="prenom" required placeholder="Prénom" value="<?php if( ! empty($prenom) ) echo $prenom; ?>" /> 

    </div>

    <div class="form_row">

        <input type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Identifiant" value="<?php if( ! empty($username) ) echo $username; ?>" />

    </div>

    <div class="form_row"> 

        <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Adresse e-mail" value="<?php if( ! empty($email) ) echo $email; ?>" /> 

    </div>

    <select id="acf-field_5d3f09ea80429" class="" name="acf[field_5d3f09ea80429]" data-ui="0" data-ajax="0" data-multiple="0" data-placeholder="Choisir" data-allow_null="0"><option value="collectivites">Collectivités</option><option value="acteur_publique">Acteur publique</option><option value="chercheur">Chercheur</option><option value="citoyen">Citoyen</option><option value="travailleur_social">Travailleur social</option><option value="entreprise">Entreprise</option><option value="autre">Autre</option></select>

    <div class="form_row"> 

        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Mot de Passe" value="<?php if( ! empty($password) ) echo $password; ?>"/>

    </div>

    <div class="form_row"> 

        <input id="password_check" type="password" name="password_check" required placeholder="Répétez votre Mot de Passe" value="<?php if( ! empty($password_check) ) echo $password_check; ?>" />

    </div>

    <div id="password-strength-status"><div class="alert_form"></div></div>

    <div class="form_row row_submit">

        <input type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" name="submit" value="S'inscrire" /> 

    </div>

</form>

<?php } else {

echo "Registration is currently disabled. Please try again later."; 

}

} ?>
```